# How to include the character \mathcal{I} in latex expression of julia plot?

Tags: julia

I am trying to make a plot with the math symbol:

[image: \m]

in the ylabel, which appears in latex as "\mathcal{I}", but this specific symbol cannot be made in Plots.jl. When entering "\mathcal{I}", you instead get:

[image: \m]

Here is a MWE:

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings

plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}")
```

Which produces:

[image]

The wrong symbol on the y-axis. I have also tried putting "\mathcal{J}" but this does not work either. I have many many plots, entire libraries really, written using Julia Plots. The convention in my field is to use "\mathcal{I}" and so it would be a great pain for me to change everything in my paper to use "\mathcal{J}" just because this one library cannot print the right symbol. I know this is latex specific stack exchange and not Julia, but I thought maybe someone knows a latex trick that would work regardless of it being Julia.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I include the output of \mathcal{I J} below:

[image]

Comment: what fonts are you using, some make I look a lot like J (history is complicated:-) eg `\usepackage{mathptmx}` mathcal I J produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkDoM.png)   where the I is different from J but looks more like a J than an I

Comment: Thank you. Your comment led to me to search out font packages and find which Plots.jl is using. I did not find that information directly, but the very last post here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/nice-fonts-with-plots-gr-and-latexstrings/60037/18, seems to indicate that changing which package it uses will be impossible. Bummer.

Comment: what does `\mathcal{I J}` look like? is it like the image I link to above where if you look hard enough at the I next to J you can convince yourself it is an I ?

Comment: I have updated my post to include what you ask about. They look very different and I think I cannot work with either unfortunately

Comment: OK but your update confirms that there is no problem with julia or its latex parsing, you are getting the I from the font not the J, you "just" don't like the font.  Hard to tell you how to change font in your pipeline (and it may not  be on topic here if it's mathjax)

Comment: Ahh okay well that is helpful if there is some mathjax forum I can ask on. I know it is mathjax as I have read that this is the case all over the place. And yes I have realised that it is just because the library is using an incorrect font family. Changing this is difficult and I am still looking into it. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing calligraphic **I** and **J** but just in a font that makes them look similar.

It's not the default calligraphic used in latex or mathjax, for example if you use `\mathcal{IJ}` in the MathJax as installed at math.stackexchange you get

[image]

However if you go far enough back in time I and J were essentially the same letter [[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J)], so designers of fonts with historic references such as calligraphic script fonts not uncommonly end up making them quite similar, a compromise between historical accuracy and present day usability.

I don't quite recognise the font you are using but you see something similar with `mathptmx`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}

$\mathcal{IJ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]